# Read environment variables in web.config

Tags: asp.net, web-config

Is there a way write code in web.config file using preprocessed function. Say I created environment variables like %Temp%, %WINDIR%.  order to read these I can use the configurationManager class. But I dont want to use it. I woudl like to use a preprocessed function similar to timeStampPattern="{timestamp(local)}". Here timestamp(local) retrieves the value directly. So in a similar way can i read the environment variables %temp% and %windir% using preprocessed function if any exists?

Comment: Why do you need temp or windir folder in asp.net application?

Answer (score 2):

No. There's no way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for Environment.getenvironmentvariable()?  You will need to find and replace them yourself.

Answer (score 2):

It can be done.

That is all you need to do: value="${envVarKey}

where envVarKey any environment variable.